# Structural recursion on two arguments

Tags: coq

I have tried to make a function in Coq which has a pretty complex termination argument. To make it easier, I am able to write the function so that it has a natural number as first argument, so that either the number or the argument after it is structurally smaller.

When trying the nested fix approach to recursion on two arguments, Coq complains that a proof argument that contains the semantics of the decreasing number is not an inductive type.

I could probably do well-founded recursion manually, but I would like to use Program Fixpoint or Equations. With Program Fixpoint I get a very ugly version of the well-foundedness proof. Below is a minimal code example that demonstrates the ugliness.

```
Require Import Program Omega.

Inductive tuple_lt : (nat * nat) -> (nat * nat) -> Prop :=
  fst_lt : forall a b c d, a < c -> tuple_lt (a, b) (c, d).

Program Fixpoint f (a : nat) (b : nat) {measure (a, b) (tuple_lt)} :=
match a with
| 0 => 0
| S n => f n b
end.

Next Obligation.
apply fst_lt. auto.
Qed.

Next Obligation.
unfold well_founded. unfold MR.
```

The obligation looks like this:

```
forall a : {_ : nat & nat}, Acc (fun x y : {_ : nat & nat} => tuple_lt (projT1 x, projT2 x) (projT1 y, projT2 y)) a
```

Can I somehow transform a proof of `Acc tuple_lt` into that ugly proof or avoid generating it?

Is there a proof in the standard library for structural recursion on two arguments?

How do I even write a manual WF proof using Equations? The manual does not mention that.

Comment: I answered to the main question of the post. I did not comment on the second paragraph, that I don't understand, and I did not tackle Equations either.

Comment: Regarding the Equations case, you can have something like the following (not sure if I understood correctly, but this is your fix to your original problem, right?):
`Equations foo p1 p2 : return_type by wf (size1 p1 + size2 p2) := `


So basically you have measures for each param you think will decrease (`size1` and `size2`) and just check the sum (or you can do something more convoluted if you want...). Equations will generally manage to automatically check that the recursive calls are ok (otherwise you have to prove it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple cases like this one, you shouldn't have to unfold definitions such as `well_founded` and `MR`, but rather use appropriate lemmas.

To deal with `MR`, you can use lemma `measure_wf` in Program.Wf.

To prove the well-foundedness of `tuple_lt`, you can rely on lemmas showing the well-foundedness of a relation based on the well-foundedness of another relation. Here, we can use `well_founded_lt_compat`. In other cases, you may find other lemmas useful, such as `wf_inverse_image`, `well_founded_ltof` or `well_founded_gtof`.

The proof of the well-foundedness of `tuple_lt` becomes simple.

```
Lemma tuple_lt_wf : well_founded tuple_lt.
Proof.
  apply well_founded_lt_compat with fst.
  intros ? ? []; assumption.
Defined.
```

And so does the proof of the second obligation.

```
Next Obligation.
apply measure_wf. apply tuple_lt_wf.
Defined.
```

(Note that in both cases, you should end the proofs with `Defined` instead of `Qed`, if you want your function defined by `Program Fixpoint` to compute inside Coq (otherwise it gets stuck on opaque proofs); it seems that you can end the proof of the first obligation with `Qed`, though).

You could also use the following simpler definition for `tuple_lt`:

```
Definition tuple_lt (p1 p2 : nat * nat) := fst p1 < fst p2.
```

In that case, the proof of well-foundedness is trivial.

```
Lemma tuple_lt_wf : well_founded tuple_lt.
Proof.
  apply well_founded_ltof.
Defined.
```

Comment: Looks like measure_wf was the thing I was missing. I'll try this later today.

Comment: tuple_lt is complex, because my actual code compares both sides.

Comment: You can also show that a lexicographic order is well-founded, given that the two orders which it is based on are well-founded too.